# sms content provider in android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

what the difference between Timestamp and Date column in SMS content provider? can any one tell me how to get list of message based on specified date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have details about columns: ( however, it really depends on URI, you will use for a query )
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/provider/Telephony.java#Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns

```
The date the message was sent
Type: INTEGER (long)
public static final String DATE = "date";
```

Code for getting messages for given date (you need READ_SMS permission):

```
final Cursor myMessages = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), new String[] { "address", "_id", "body", "type", "date", "read", "thread_id" }, "date > your_timestamp", null, "date ASC");
```